# Как проверить с помощью JavaScript, поддерживает ли браузер CSS медиа запросы?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Как проверить с помощью JavaScript, поддерживает ли браузер CSS медиа запросы `@media (min-width) {...}` ?

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно проверить так

```
function mediaQueriesSupported() {
    return (typeof window.matchMedia == 'function');
}
```

однако лучше использовать кастомный билд [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) для проверки поддержки браузером нужных фич.